# React props not correctly set when wrapping an input

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to create a React Component that wraps an input and pass the value of the changed input to its parents.
I'm able to pass the event to the parent by just delegating the onchange function trought props, but i would prefer to encapsulate the extraction of the new value from the event IN the child component.

Here is my Component code :

```
class BigInputField extends React.Component<IBigInputField, {}>{
  handleChange(event){
    console.log("handleChange method called !");
    debugger;
    let value = event && event.target && event.target.value;
    this.props.onChangeSetValue(value);
  };
  render(){
    return (
        <input type="search" value = {this.props.value} onChange= {this.handleChange} id="main_search_field" className="form-control" placeholder="Stuff to input"/>
    );
  }
}
```

The problem is that when i enter something into the input, react complains that this.props.onChangeSetValue(value) is not a function.
When i inspect this.props at the debugger statement, i get a className member of value "form-control", a placeholder of value "Stuff to input" an id of value "main_search_field" ....
It seems that instead of getting the props transfered by the parent, i get the props of the children rendered by my component !
This is perhaps a problem with the chrome debugger, that doesn't correctly set the this value, but it doesn't explain why my this.props.onChangeSetValue doesn't seems to exist.

In the parent, the prop is set like this:

```
<BigInputField onChangeSetValue= {this.setSearchValue} value= this.state.search}/>
```

and i have checked in the render function of the parent that "this.setSearchValue" is the correct function.

How do you explain this ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you bind `this` to your component?  When using es6 extends in React components, you should be doing something like this:

```
class BigInputField extends React.Component<IBigInputField, {}>{
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        //need to bind custom functions to the component due to how extends works in es6
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    }
    ...
    render () { // return here }
}
```

Comment: Another relevant question: Does the component have a constructor that takes props and calls super(props) like in tells' snippet?

Comment: Thank you, i had read it in the React doc, but forgot it.

_No Autobinding
Methods follow the same semantics as regular ES6 classes, meaning that they don't automatically bind this to the instance. You'll have to explicitly use .bind(this) or arrow functions =>._

But i prefer this way:
`render(){
    return (
        <input type="search" value = {this.props.value} onChange= {this.handleChange.bind(this)} id="main_search_field" className="form-control" placeholder="Stuff to input"/>
    );
  }`
Which doesn't force me to implement the constructor (at least i guess).

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation, when using ES6 classes, there is not autobinding of method passed in render like with React.createClass, i have to bind them like this in the render method:

```
render(){
    return (
        <input type="search" value = {this.props.value} onChange= {this.handleChange.bind(this)} id="main_search_field" className="form-control" placeholder="Stuff to input"/>
    );
  }
```

Notice the *bind* after `this.handlechange`